# alignment of multiple divs correctly in css - only css

Tags: html, css

js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cdc03s6e/

Please help to align the collection  of divs

It should be like

```
Tea    Radio Starting Date TextBox Percentage TextBox %  Name    TextBox
Coffee Radio Starting Date TextBox Percentage TextBox %  Company TextBox
```

As i will use this two lines of collection many places , so need a general class 
css

```
<div class=parentClass>
<div><label>Tea</label></div>
<div><input type=radio></div>
<div><label>Starting Date</label></div>
<div><input type=text class=smallTextBox></div>
<div><label>percentage</label></div>
<div><input type=text class=smallTextBox></div>
<div><label>%</label></div>
<div><label>name</label></div>
<div><input type=text class=smallTextBox></div>
</div>

<div class=parentClass>
<div><label>Coffee</label></div>
<div><input type=radio></div>
<div><label>Starting Date</label></div>
<div><input type=text class=smallTextBox></div>
<div><label>Percentage</label></div>
<div><input type=text class=smallTextBox></div>
<div><label>%</label></div>
<div><label>Company</label></div>
<div><input type=text class=smallTextBox></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.smallTextBox
{width:50px;}

.parentClass {

  > div:nth-child(1) {
    //
  display:inline;
  }

  > div:nth-child(2) {
    //
  display:inline;
  }
}
```

Can use table tag

Comment: you want this list aligned in orizzontal?

Comment: yaa  same as i gave

Comment: If you do not want to use table styling, would flex-box be an option ?

Comment: yup that can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do it is with css `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`.

Based on your example I'm assuming you use Sass or Less.

```
.parentClass {
    display:table-row;

    > div { 
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit since you can't use css tables**: If you don't mind that every element in the row has the same width (so the width doesn't adjust to fit content), you can use flexbox to achieve the table-like look.

```
.parentClass {
    display: flex;

    > div {
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-basis: 0;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdc03s6e/3/)

Comment: cant use any kind of table style

Comment: flex one is nice , but how to control this one

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? I've used a combination of `block` and `inline-block`. https://jsfiddle.net/cdc03s6e/1/

Comment: Ok, then the CSS table solution is the easiest. Or use an HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

TeaStarting Datepercentage% name

Use only one div and add elements in it

Comment: one div will not align it like what i wrote in question

Comment: Is it complasory to use only css otherwise

<div class=parentClass>
<label>Tea</label>
<input type=radio>
<label>Starting Date</label>
<input type=text class=smallTextBox>
<label>percentage</label>
<input type=text class=smallTextBox>
<label>%</label>
<label> name</label>
<input type=text class=smallTextBox>
</div>

You can use this way

Answer (score 0):

The best way to align this type of layout is using of tables for best user experience. Check below code:

```css
.smallTextBox {
  width: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<table class=parentClass>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Tea</label></td>
    <td><input type=radio></td>
    <td><label>Starting Date</label></td>
    <td><input type=text class=smallTextBox></td>
    <td><label>percentage</label></td>
    <td><input type=text class=smallTextBox></td>
    <td><label>%</label></td>
    <td><label>name</label></td>
    <td><input type=text class=smallTextBox></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Coffee</label></td>
    <td><input type=radio></td>
    <td><label>Starting Date</label></td>
    <td><input type=text class=smallTextBox></td>
    <td><label>Percentage</label></td>
    <td><input type=text class=smallTextBox></td>
    <td><label>%</label></td>
    <td><label>Company</label></td>
    <td><input type=text class=smallTextBox></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```